# Show Input tag(textbox control) with two digit format in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

How can I make an input tag, that always accepts two digits? like 01, 02, 03 etc up to 24. A leading zero should be present in case of single digits(0 to 9)

```
<input id="hourInput" type="number" min="1" max="24" step="1"  />
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible, in pure HTML5, to achieve this. Javascript will be required...

```
<input id="hourInput" type="number" min="1" max="24" step="1" onchange="if(parseInt(this.value,10)<10)this.value='0'+this.value;" />
```

EDIT:
Since this answer seems to get good trafic, I'd like to add the fact that the approach I have suggested is a naïve way to do it and will only correctly work with a min attribute higher than -9. If the number goes lower, the 0 will still get added resulting in 0-234 when the user enter a negative value of 234.

Comment: Will also work: 
<input id="hourInput" type="number" min="1" max="24" step="1" onchange="if( this.value.length == 1 ) this.value='0'+this.value;" />

Comment: I have created an angular js directive using this concept,  https://github.com/ksnimmy/txDataType

Comment: I think, if you use the input event, the behavior will be better.

Comment: That's a good idea, this can make things slightly better, but I feel it is out of the scope of the OP tough.

Comment: Doesn't work on Firefox, works on Chrome (I just tested those two). In Firefox, it seems that you can programmatically change the number, but it won't let you re-format a number lower than 10 to two digits.

Comment: This is well known https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1005603 Your option would be to opt for an input of type text instead. But that would open the full keyboard instead of the numeric one. You could hack a hidden number input on top of the text one, that would receive inputs and update the visual one...

Answer (score 9):

There is no native way to do that. However you can use oninput event to format.

```
    <input id="hourInput" type="number" oninput='format(this)' min="1" max="24" step="1"  />
```

Javascript

```
function format(input){
  if(input.value.length === 1){
    input.value = "0" + input.value;
  }
}
```

http://jsbin.com/dedixapasi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Great!, However, more simple way: <input id="hourInput" type="number" min="1" max="24" step="1" onchange="if(this.value.length < 2) this.value = '0' + this.value;">

Answer (score 0):

You can also do using JQuery like following:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#hourInput").keydown(function(event) {
  if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 ) {
   
  }
  else {
   if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57 ) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
   } 
  }
 });
    $("#hourInput").keyup(function(event) {
        var str = $('#hourInput').val();
        if(str > 24)
        {
            $('#hourInput').val(str.substring(0,str.length - 1));
        }
        
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="hourInput" type="number" min="1" step="1" />
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function format(input){
    if(input.value < 0) input.value=Math.abs(input.value);
    if(input.value.length > 2) input.value = input.value.slice(0, 2);
    $(input).blur(function() {
       // if(input.value.length == 1) input.value=0+input.value;
       // if(input.value.length == 0) input.value='01';
       //* if you want to allow insert only 2 digits *//
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" name="number" step="1" oninput="format(this)">
```

It works for me... hope for you as well :)